# valgrind: errors (mistmatched free() / delete/ delete[] )

Tags: c++, arrays, valgrind, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator

So valgrind is giving me this error:

```
Mismatched free() / delete / delete []
```

Which is referring to the following line of code:

```
delete[] data[position+num];
```

but the error keeps appearing even after i change it to

```
delete data[position+num];
```

the data array was allocated in the following manner:

```
data = new char*[width];
    for (int i=0; i<width; ++i){
            data[i] = new char;
    }
```

I just want to delete that one column of (char **data).

Also, below that error i get the following:

Address 0x5a1c160 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 1 alloc'd

```
==21417==    at 0x4C2B800: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
```

Comment: It was not "data array" that was allocated- it was an array of pointers.
Data[0] is a pointer to char, data[1] is a pointer to char and so on.
With delete[] data[position+num] you say "delete an array of something which is the same type as data[position+num], it's located in data[position+num]", so you say "delete an array of pointers to char", but you actually store a single pointer to char there. Afaik that's undefined behaviour in std, but compilers get with it anyway. Unfortunately, i don't know why you get an error with delete data[position+num], it seems to be a valid statement for me

Comment: i've never used valgrind to be honest. Also, it's 2015, you'll get many responses like "don't ever use new/delete" ;)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you mean by `delete[] data[position+num];`. Your code also looks a bit dubious: `data` is an array of pointers-to-char, i.e. array of C-like strings, but in the loop you allocate to each pointer a single `char` via `data[i] = new char;`. Are you sure that's what you want? Usually you allocate a bunch, `data[i] = new char[some_length];`.

In any case, you need to `delete` in reverse order of allocation:

```
for (int i=0; i<width; ++i){
       delete data[i]; // or delete[] data[i] if pointing to more than one char
}
delete[] data;
```

Or, better, don't use `new` and `delete` at all, and use standard containers like `std::vector<std::string>`. If you allocate more than one `char`, then use `delete[]` instead.

Comment: What if you just wanted to delete that one row a 2D array?

Comment: Which row? the one `data[i]` points to for some specific `i`?

Comment: Then just do `delete data[10]` for example to deallocate the memory of the 10-th row. But this won't magically "shift" the other rows, as you may expect. In general, you need to deallocate when `data` is not needed anymore, and you better de-allocate all of it, otherwise you'll end up with a memory leak. But again, please use `std::vector<std::string>` instead, is much much less prone to errors.